# Angular ng-include onload method not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

I am using foundation and angular for the most part I have it working but ran into a small problem. I am using foundation tabs and when my angular controller wires it up the first tab seems duplicated and when I click on any other tab it always stacks on top of the first tab.

Weird thing is when I tinker with any css style in the inspector it just magically works. For example if I toggle any style anywhere. I am also able to get it to work if I run an alert that is fired onload of ng-include. I thought a setTimeout would do the trick but that didn't work. Below please review my code and let me know what you think might be the problem and or if I have done something incorrectly. Thanks and any assistance is appreciated.

**JS**

```
.controller('MyAppCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabs =  [
        { tabID:'0', title:'title1', content:'templates/tab-one.html'},
        { tabID:'1', title:'title2', content:'templates/tab-two.html'},
        { tabID:'2', title:'title3', content:'templates/tab-three.html'}
    ];
    $scope.currentIndex = 0;
    $scope.initTabs = function () {
        alert($scope.currentIndex);
    };
    $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function(index) {
        return $scope.currentIndex === index;
    }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" content="  
    {{tab.content}}" active="tab.active">
        <ng-include onload="initTabs($index)" src="tab.content"></ng-include>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: `ng-init` on `tabset`? `ng-repeat` and `ng-inclue` has its own scope.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I am trying to resolve is the first tab not unloading when I navigate the other tabs. Weird thing is when I tinker with the styles in Chromes web inspector it unloads the first tab and things look fine. I also noticed when I resize the window that it resolves the issue as well.

Comment: I think you need to provide a plnkr to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trouble shooting I was able to figure out what was causing the problem with the tab content not displaying properly. When using Angular with the Foundation framework port you can only use the css and not the sass as soon as I removed the sass imports everything displayed properly. I initially thought this issue was being caused by the onload in the ng-include but after reading the documentation on Angular Foundation I realized that the sass option was not yet supported just the css option.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NxUf1JIsYVofeEmV0E3K?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/mm-foundation-tpls-0.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.2.0/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
<tabset>
<tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
  {{tab.content}}
</tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what the problem is, but looking at your code I've spotted something that it can't be wright:

Your function `initTabs` doesn't take any parameters, but when you call it you are passing the `$index` of the tabs, maybe you wanted that function to look like this:

```
$scope.initTabs = function(index) {...}
```

If this doesn't help, could you please add a link to jsFiddle or to Plunker with an example of your problem, so that we can reproduce it and try to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I updated that. Not the issue really. I will put something on jsfiddle hopefully that will better communicate my issues.